# Lost write access after transferring a repo

Tags: github

I have a repo created under my personal account https://github.com/ice1000/properties-devkt (it's a fork now), I go to Settings, disabled issues and projects, and transferred the repo to an organization https://github.com/devkt-plugins created by me (I'm the owner of it), and now it becomes https://github.com/devkt-plugins/properties-devkt.

After transferring this repo, I lost write access to it. This is also why I forked this repo to my personal account.

But how is that possible? Am I going to lost write access to a repo which previously owned by me and now owned by my organization?

[image]